# Good zoom and annotation tool for Linux

Tags: linux, desktop

I am searching for a **great zoom and annotation tool** for Linux, something similar to [Sysinternals Zoom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit). I am using Linux Mint and default magnifier is ok, but missing annotations for demonstration purposes.

What kind of tools do you use for zooming around with default hotkey and being able to lock and draw something on top of it?

Thanks you for any pointers or links.